# Adding or replacing image size

Tags: images, block-editor, regex

I have a lot posts converted from classic editor to block editor and in the process, some image blocks (or all) have missing `sizeSlug` attribute, which editor interpretes as thumbnail size. However, I have new posts as well and they have size slug. I want to add to all image blocks attribute sizeSlug set to 'large', which are missing this attribute.

I would know how to do it with wp cli and regex if it weren't for those posts which already have this attribute and who should not be touched.

Example of markup of image without `sizeSlug`:

```
<!-- wp:image {"align":"center","id":13431,"linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image aligncenter"><a href="https://host/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/friends.jpg"><img src="https://host/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/friends.jpg" alt="Friends" class="wp-image-13431"/></a></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->
```

Solution which affects all block images, which adds sizeSlug to all image blocks:

```
wp search-replace '(<!-- wp:image\s{[^}]*)' '$1,"sizeSlug":"full"' wp_posts --regex --regex-delimiter='/'
```

The answer does not have to be wp cli based.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this regex does the trick:

```
wp search-replace '(<!-- wp:image\s{(?!.*"sizeSlug")[^}]*)' '$1,\"sizeSlug\":\"full\"' wp_posts --regex --regex-delimiter='/' --precise
```

EDIT:
I added correction, double quotes must be escaped in replacement string in order for this to work properly. It seems that everything is first encoded in json, hence the reason.

ANOTHER EDIT:
This did the trick by updating post content by adding attribute, but srcset and sizes are still missing.